# Storing a SQL string array, and subsequent querying

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

I want to store a variable size list of image tags in a SQL database and then be able to search the database for images based on the tags. I am currently pulling the tag lists out of the database, and checking if the query tag is contained in the array. Is there any way I can format these as sql queries instead of doing them in php after I pull the tags out?

The list is stored as comma separated values of the form:

"sunny, beach, palms" -im1

"palms, rainy, clouds" -im2

"winter, snow, snowman, swag" -img

I would like to be able to get the union of the query tags:
A query of "beach, palms" should return im1 and im2

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll want to avoid delimited lists in your database-- as you've found, that negates the advantages of using a database to store structured data.  Instead you should create a new table with one tag per row, and then reference that table, using a *foreign key*, from your main images table.

**Images** Table

- id
- image_name

**Tags** Table

- id
- tag_name

**Image_Tags** Table

- image_id (references Images table primary key)
- tag_id (references Tags table primary key)

This way, you'll be able to run queries like this:

```
SELECT t.tag_name, i.image_name FROM image_tags it
    INNER JOIN images i on it.image_id = i.id
    INNER JOIN tags t on it.tag_id = t.id
WHERE t.tag_name in ('beach', 'palms')
```

Comment: Great answer. This is the second time this visit I've seen people using lists of values inside a DB and wanting to search them... What's the point of relational DB without relations :P

Comment: Thank you. I actually found this pretty good article that describes two other ways of doing it. http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html#toxi

Answer (score 7):

@dbaseman provided a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10273989/533120) (+1), but it *might* be a bit of an overkill. Assuming the only thing you want to know about a tag is its name, the model with only 2 tables will probably behave better in practice (one less JOIN and better [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering) of data):

image table:

- id PK
- image_name

image_tag table:

- tag_name PK
- image_id PK, FK -> image

The order of fields in image_tag's PK is important: if you keep it as `{tag_name, image_id}` it will nicely cluster the data (i.e. keep images with same tags together), exactly as you need it for querying:

```
SELECT DISTINCT image.*
FROM image JOIN image_tag ON (image.id = image_tag.image_id)
WHERE image_tag.tag_name IN ('beach', 'palms')
```

On the other hand, if you also need a tag description, tag author etc..., @dbaseman's model is fine, except you might consider flipping the order of fields in Image_Tags PK (for the same clustering reasons as above).